# Need a text Filter per column in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a userList app that I need to be able to do searches using strings in each column. The app itself looks like this: [app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5hg7.png)

I have tried different variations I can find, from pure JS code to Vue functions. Last thing I've tried is as follows (this is only for the first name search, will need to duplicate it for the other columns):

```
    <template>
  <table id="tblUsers">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="firstNameFilter"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="lastNameFilter"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="usernameFilter"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="emailFilter"/></td>
        <td>
          <select id="statusFilter">
            <option value="">Show All</option>
            <option value="Active">Active</option>
            <option value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- user listing goes here -->
      <tr2 v-for="userList in users" :key='userList'>
        <td2> {{userList.firstName}} </td2>
        <td2> {{userList.lastName}} </td2>
        <td2> {{userList.username}} </td2>
        <td2> {{userList.emailAddress}} </td2>
        <td2> {{userList.status}} </td2>  
      </tr2>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<script>

function myFilter() {
  let input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("firstNameFilter");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("tblUsers")
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr2");
}

for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
  td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td2")[0];
  if (td) {
    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      tr[i].style.dusplay="";
    } else {
      tri[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}



export default {
  name: 'user-list',
  data() {
    return {
      users: [
        { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith', username: 'jsmith', emailAddress: 'jsmith@gmail.com', status: 'Active' },
        { firstName: 'Anna', lastName: 'Bell', username: 'abell', emailAddress: 'abell@yahoo.com', status: 'Active' },
        { firstName: 'George', lastName: 'Best', username: 'gbest', emailAddress: 'gbest@gmail.com', status: 'Disabled' },
        { firstName: 'Ben', lastName: 'Carter', username: 'bcarter', emailAddress: 'bcarter@gmail.com', status: 'Active' },
        { firstName: 'Katie', lastName: 'Jackson', username: 'kjackson', emailAddress: 'kjackson@yahoo.com', status: 'Active' },
        { firstName: 'Mark', lastName: 'Smith', username: 'msmith', emailAddress: 'msmith@foo.com', status: 'Disabled' }
      ]
    };
  },
};


</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You seem to be trying to use view as if it were jQuery.  The beauty of vue is it saves you from having to parse the DOM with getElementsByTagName and such.  Your methods should operate directly on the data, and vue automatically updates the DOM for you.  For details, see the vue intro docs.

Comment: What are `<tr2>` and `<td2>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example, Ive just done a search filter based off any object value.

You can modify this for each type if you wish but this example should give you a runnin start on how vue works :)

As you can see ive used something called `v-model` this is essentially binding the value of that input to a variable in the data object.

Now that you have this you can filter the users based off a computed property that returns all the users if the filters blank or the filtered users if its not.

My search filter is also an exact match, You will want to change this to something like string starts with.

```
    <template>
  <table id="tblUsers">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="search" v-model="filter_string" placeholder="Filter Users"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="firstNameFilter"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="lastNameFilter"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="usernameFilter"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="emailFilter"/></td>
        <td>
          <select id="statusFilter">
            <option value="">Show All</option>
            <option value="Active">Active</option>
            <option value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- user listing goes here -->
      <tr2 v-for="userList in results" :key='userList'>
        <td2> {{userList.firstName}} </td2>
        <td2> {{userList.lastName}} </td2>
        <td2> {{userList.username}} </td2>
        <td2> {{userList.emailAddress}} </td2>
        <td2> {{userList.status}} </td2>  
      </tr2>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'user-list',
  data() {
    return {
      filter_string: '',
      users: [
        { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith', username: 'jsmith', emailAddress: 'jsmith@gmail.com', status: 'Active' },
        { firstName: 'Anna', lastName: 'Bell', username: 'abell', emailAddress: 'abell@yahoo.com', status: 'Active' },
        { firstName: 'George', lastName: 'Best', username: 'gbest', emailAddress: 'gbest@gmail.com', status: 'Disabled' },
        { firstName: 'Ben', lastName: 'Carter', username: 'bcarter', emailAddress: 'bcarter@gmail.com', status: 'Active' },
        { firstName: 'Katie', lastName: 'Jackson', username: 'kjackson', emailAddress: 'kjackson@yahoo.com', status: 'Active' },
        { firstName: 'Mark', lastName: 'Smith', username: 'msmith', emailAddress: 'msmith@foo.com', status: 'Disabled' }
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
      results() {
          return this.filter_string === '' ? this.users : this.users.filter(user => {
              return Object.values(user).map(string => string.toLowerCase()).includes(this.filter_string.toLowerCase())
          })
      }
  }
};


</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is definitely a good starting point! I appreciate the help.